# I dont know what is the problem in my code when i open this app my app crashes

Tags: android, android-studio

```
     package com.example.shery.tictactoe;

 import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.TextView;

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9;
 TextView tv1;
String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    btn3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    btn5 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn5);
    btn6 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn6);
    btn7 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn7);
    btn8 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn8);
    btn9 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn1.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn1.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btn1.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn1.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    });
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn2.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn2.setEnabled(false);

            }
            else
            {
                btn2.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn2.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    });
    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn3.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn3.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btn3.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn3.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    });
    btn4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();

            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn4.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn4.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btn4.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn4.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    });
    btn5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();

            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn5.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn5.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btn5.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn5.setEnabled(false);
            }

        }
    });
    btn6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();

            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn6.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn6.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btn6.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn6.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    });
    btn7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();

            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn7.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn7.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btn7.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn7.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    });
    btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();

            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn8.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn8.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btn8.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn8.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    });
    btn8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();

            if(field1.equals("Turn X"))
            {
                btn9.setText("X");
                tv1.setText("Turn O");
                btn9.setEnabled(false);
            }
            else
            {
                btn9.setText("O");
                tv1.setText("Turn X");
                btn9.setEnabled(false);

            }

        }
    });



}
```

}

I dont know what is the problem in my code when i open this app my app crashes you can check my code above I dont know what is the problem in my code when i open this app my app crashes look like open app again why is this happen when i was written 2 btn click listener the app wok fine but when i add more click listner my app crashes why??

Comment: Please share your layout file and the crash log so we can help you.

Comment: inmy logcat java.lana.nullpointet exception is coming

Comment: Issue is with this line `String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();`. You have called this globally. This will not work until you have called findViewById() for tv1.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.shery.tictactoe/com.example.shery.tictactoe.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException:

Comment: you can check i have also initialize this

Answer (score 0):

`String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();` cannot be called globally. Do this in OnCreate method after defining `tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);`

Answer (score 0):

> String field1 = tv1.getText().toString();

Before getting your answer you must understood why this error occurs and how to prevent it. You must learn lifecycle of activity and you have some clear idea about this.

And the problem is textview cannot initialize outside of onCreate(). Because the view is rendered only inside of onCreate() method.That only you get null pointer exception. Rewrite the code as below. Your problem is solved.

```
String field;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    field1 = tv1.getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first in `onCreate` :

---

```
tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
```

then second line :

```
 field1 = tv1.getText().toString();
```

---